# Grails auto update related table

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have following domain classes:

```
class UserGroup {
    String name
    String description
    static hasMany = [users:User]
}

class User {

    String name
    static hasMany = [userGroups:UserGroup]
    static belongsTo = UserGroup
}
```

Here User and UserGroup have many to many relationaship.but when I save user to usergroup,the user is not updated with that usergroup.Is there a mapping I can use to do that?I am using following code to add users to group:

```
static def addUserToGroups(def user){
        def userGroups = UserGroup.findAll()
        userGroups.each {
            if(/** condition **/){
                it.addToUsers(user)
                it.save(flush:true,failOnError:true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Don't you see the relation in the XREF table?

Comment: There is no error.user is successfully added to user group,but reverse doesn't happen automatically.The user group is not added to user.I have the tables user_group_users and user_user_group in database